# how to join uuid to name with tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql tabels, one with `uuid` and c_id and another with `c_id` and `name`
I want to get the `name` from the `uuid`

```
table_a:        table_b:
uuid    c_id    c_id    name
1-2-3   1       2       dad
3-2-1   2       1       mom
```

I have in a php var the `uuid` and I want to get `name`, How is this possible?
I think I need to use join, just not sure how.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.name
  from table_a a
  join table_b b
    on a.c_id = b.c_id
 where a.uuid = 'your_php_var_here'
```

Comment: I got an errror

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 119
STR: =\
SQL: SELECT `campaigns`.`name` FROM `pixels` JOIN `campaigns` ON `pixels`.`cam_id` = `campaigns`.`id` WHERE `pixels`.`uuid`='D1F53'

SELECT `campaigns`.`name` FROM `pixels` JOIN `campaigns` ON `pixels`.`cam_id` = `campaigns`.`id` WHERE `pixels`.`uuid`='D1F53'

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'D1F53' at line 1

Comment: @phper what error? If you copy and paste the above sql and run it against the database and it has no error on the database side, then it has to do with your php code